# Passing an expression as a parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to build a generic `GroupBy` Method, I guess it should be something like this

```
var result = GenericGroupBy<List<DTO>>(dataList, g=>g.Id);

public object GenericGroupBy<T>(object data, Func<T, bool> groupByExpression)
{
    return ((List<T>)data).GroupBy(groupByExpression);
}
```

But I can not make it work.

How to pass expression like `g=>g.Id`?

Comment: Well currently your method accepts a parameter which takes a `T` and returns a `bool`... and I doubt that `g.Id` is a bool. Likewise I suspect you want a type argument of `DTO`, not `List<DTO>`.

Comment: What is the type of the `dataList` variable (not the actual runtime type, but just the compile time type)?

Comment: If you know `T` statically, why not define `data` as `List<T>` instead of `object`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Changing `List<DTO>` to `DTO` and `Func<T, bool>` to `Func<T, int>` worked. Can you add the comment as an Answer, I'll accept it...

Comment: @Nalaka526 At that point there's really no reason to have this method.   You should just be calling `GroupBy`.  This method is adding no real value at all.  All it's doing is taking away value by casting the return type to `object`, making it almost worthless.

Comment: @Servy Yes you are correct... But the code I've posted is just a sample to show the problem I've faced, my actual method is bit different. And it is specific to the domain and make no sense for the question. That's why this method looks silly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are two problems:

- Your method expects a `Func<T, bool>` and I suspect `g => g.Id` fails that because your `Id` property isn't a `bool`
- You're currently specifying `List<DTO>` as the type argument, when I suspect you really want just `DTO`.

Given your comments, this will work:

```
var result = GenericGroupBy<DTO>(dataList, g => g.Id);

public object GenericGroupBy<T>(object data, Func<T, int> groupByExpression)
{
    return ((List<T>)data).GroupBy(groupByExpression);
}
```

... but I'd make it a bit more general unless you *always* want to group by `int`:

```
var result = GenericGroupBy<DTO, int>(dataList, g => g.Id);

public object GenericGroupBy<TElement, TKey>
    (object data, Func<TElement, TKey> groupByExpression)
{
    return ((IEnumerable<TElement>)data).GroupBy(groupByExpression);
}
```

Note how I've also changed the cast from `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` - you don't *need* it to be a `List<T>`, so why cast to that?